# Merge object with arrays

Tags: javascript, lodash

I'd like to merge objects with arrays but it seems not working as expected.

I'd like to concat arrays but keep unique items by "label".

**First object :**

```
var object1 = {
  index: [
    {
      label: 'Ajouter',
      url: '/_add/:model',
      icon: 'add',
      isMain: true
    },
    {
      label: 'Exporter en CSV',
      url: '/_export/:model',
      icon: 'cloud_download'
    },
    {
      label: 'Accès à l\'API',
      url: '/api/_index/:model',
      target: '_blank',
      icon: 'link'
    }
  ],
  add: [
    {
      label: 'Retour',
      url: '/_index/:model',
      icon: 'arrow_back'
    }
  ],
  edit: [
    {
      label: 'Retour',
      icon: 'arrow_back',
      url: '/_index/:model'
    },
    {
      label: 'Supprimer',
      icon: 'delete',
      url: '/_delete/:model/:id'
    }
  ]
};
```

**Second object :**

```
var object2 = _.mergeWith(_.clone(object1), {
  index: [
    {
      label: 'Explorateur ',
      url: '/file/_folder-explorer/uploads',
      target: '_blank',
      icon: 'folder_open'
    },
    {
      label: 'Ajout multiple ',
      url: '/file/_add-multiple',
      icon: 'library_add'
    }
  ],
  edit: [
    {
      label: 'Retour',
      icon: 'arrow_back',
      url: '/file/_index'
    }
  ]
}, customizerMergeActions);

function customizerMergeActions(objValue, srcValue) {
  if (_.isArray(objValue)) {
    return objValue.concat(srcValue);
  }
}
```

**Issue :** In the "edit" key I got the same object "label: 'Retour'", I'd like to keep the last one...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want combine two arrays, you'll need to convert them both to objects, and use the `label`'s value as the key of each. Then merge them, and convert back to an array.

```js
const fn = (key, ...objs) => _.mergeWith({}, ...objs, (v1, v2) => {
  if(!_.isArray(v1)) return;
  
  /** convert both arrays to objects indexed by the chosen key, 
      merge them using the fn (this will handle arrays inside arrays)
      and then convert back to array with _.values() **/
  return _.values(fn(key, _.keyBy(v1, key), _.keyBy(v2, key)));
});

const object1 = {"index":[{"label":"Ajouter","url":"/_add/:model","icon":"add","isMain":true},{"label":"Exporter en CSV","url":"/_export/:model","icon":"cloud_download"},{"label":"Accès à l'API","url":"/api/_index/:model","target":"_blank","icon":"link"}],"add":[{"label":"Retour","url":"/_index/:model","icon":"arrow_back"}],"edit":[{"label":"Retour","icon":"arrow_back","url":"/_index/:model"},{"label":"Supprimer","icon":"delete","url":"/_delete/:model/:id"}]};

const object2 = {"index":[{"label":"Explorateur ","url":"/file/_folder-explorer/uploads","target":"_blank","icon":"folder_open"},{"label":"Ajout multiple ","url":"/file/_add-multiple","icon":"library_add"}],"edit":[{"label":"Retour","icon":"arrow_back","url":"/file/_index"}]};

const result = fn('label', object1, object2);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.15/lodash.js"></script>
```

ES5 version:

```js
function fn(key, arr1, arr2) {
  return _.mergeWith({}, arr1, arr2, function(v1, v2) {
    if(!_.isArray(v1)) return;

    /** convert both arrays to objects indexed by the chosen key, 
        merge them using the fn (this will handle arrays inside arrays)
        and then convert back to array with _.values() **/
    return _.values(fn(key, _.keyBy(v1, key), _.keyBy(v2, key)));
  });
}

var object1 = {"index":[{"label":"Ajouter","url":"/_add/:model","icon":"add","isMain":true},{"label":"Exporter en CSV","url":"/_export/:model","icon":"cloud_download"},{"label":"Accès à l'API","url":"/api/_index/:model","target":"_blank","icon":"link"}],"add":[{"label":"Retour","url":"/_index/:model","icon":"arrow_back"}],"edit":[{"label":"Retour","icon":"arrow_back","url":"/_index/:model"},{"label":"Supprimer","icon":"delete","url":"/_delete/:model/:id"}]};

var object2 = {"index":[{"label":"Explorateur ","url":"/file/_folder-explorer/uploads","target":"_blank","icon":"folder_open"},{"label":"Ajout multiple ","url":"/file/_add-multiple","icon":"library_add"}],"edit":[{"label":"Retour","icon":"arrow_back","url":"/file/_index"}]};

var result = fn('label', object1, object2);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.15/lodash.js"></script>
```

Comment: It works in the console, but can u provide the JavaScript code and not the ES5 or ES6 code of the function. I'm using NodeJS and not the latest version.

Comment: Updated. Next time - state ES5 in your questions.

Answer (score 0):

If I got your question right, you want to overwrite values from the **source** object, i.e(the second parameter to mergeWith function), with corresponding values in **object1** variable. So, just instead of using concat function in the **customizerMergeActions** function, use this,

```
function customizerMergeActions(objValue, srcValue) {
    if (_.isArray(objValue)) {
        return _.merge(objValue, srcValue);
    }
}
```

This way, the edit key will now hold this array of objects,

```
[
    {label: "Retour", icon: "arrow_back", url: "/file/_index"},
    {label: "Supprimer", icon: "arrow_back", url: "/_delete/:model/:id"}
]
```